# Configuring Plyr player source

Tags: javascript, jquery, plyr.js

I'm trying to configue a vimeo player using the "[plyr html5 player](https://plyr.io/)". But as I try to send the source through js it simply won't work, Just gives me back the error player.source is not a function.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="p1_s2_vimeo-id" class="p1_s2-player" data-type="vimeo" data-video-id="">
```

**JS:**

```
var player = plyr.setup('.p1_s2-player', {
  html: controls
});

player.source({
  type:       'video',
  title:      'Example title',
  sources: [{
      src:    '143418951',
      type:   'vimeo'
  }]
});
```

**[The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/groseler/oxtoLvda/)**

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

This is old but I had the same issue so here is the fix:
You are using the wrong syntax to load the source, you need to use:

player.source = {
  type:       'video',
  title:      'Example title',
  sources: [{
      src:    '143418951',
      type:   'vimeo'
  }]
};